# There be no doing

Tags: phrase-meaning

Plot:

> A is a fat woman, and there is a B fatter than A.
>
> A asked her husband,
>   "B's bigger than me, right?"
>
> Her husband answered, "Yeah, **there's no getting around** her on the sidewalk."

What is the meaning of the answer? It probably means

> Yes, she is bigger than you only if you are all standing on the
>   sidewalk.

or

> Yes. So, don't stand on the sidewalk with B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are incorrect.

It means

> Yes, she is fat. People can't pass her when they are coming across her on
>   the sidewalk.